# How could proving the result of variance of estimator in Latin Hypercube Sampling

Tags: variance, sampling, monte-carlo, latin-hypercube

Ok i almost freak out of this!!!! i've to doing some presented about [this paper (M.D.MCKAY,J.BECKMAN, W.J.CONOVER (1979)](https://www.asc.ohio-state.edu/statistics/comp_exp/jour.club/McKayConoverBeckman.pdf). It's about comparing methods for selecting values **(Random Sampling, Stratifed Sampling, Latin Hypercube Sampling)**. But i really got a problem to find out and understand this proof in the paper.
Basically they are showing the result about variance of estimator for LHS.
So first we have a estimator of LHS which they defined in paper and variance of it.

[image]

And a fews next result about $w_i$ to give a final form of $Var(T_L)$
[image]

[image]

**A KEY POINT**

[image]

**My problem is how we just using *"some algebra"* to transform (8.12) become (8.13) or the form of variance of estimator for LHS as you might know.**
I've done in many way but i still can't make it to a simply form like in a paper, can anyone show me a hint or a trick to prove it, please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in the paper in (8.12):

Starting with (8.11)

$$\sum_{i=1}^{N^k} \sum_{j=1, i \ne j}^{N^k} Cov(w_i g(Y_i), w_j g(Y_j)) =
  \sum_{i \ne j} \sum \mu_i \mu_j E(w_i w_j) - N^{-2k+2} \sum_{i \ne j} \sum \mu_i \mu_j$$

And

$$E(w_i w_j) = N^{-k+1} (N-1)^{-k+1}$$

Now if we combine these two and add the factor of $1/N^2$, we can see that there was a typo

$$Var(T_L) = \frac{1}{N} Var(Y) - N^{-k-1} \sum_i (\mu_i - \tau)^2 + \\
+(N^{-k-1} - N^{-2k}) \sum_i \mu_i^2 \\
+(N-1)^{-k+1} N^{-k+1} N^{-2} \sum_R \sum \mu_i \mu_j \\
-N^{-2k+2} N^{-2} \sum_{i \ne j} \mu_i \mu_j$$

---

$$Var(T_L) = \frac{1}{N}  Var(Y) - N^{-k-1} \sum_i (\mu_i - \tau)^2 + \\
+(N^{-k-1} - N^{-2k}) \sum_i \mu_i^2 \\
+(N-1)^{-k+1} N^{-k-1} \sum_R \sum \mu_i \mu_j \\
-N^{-2k} \sum_{i \ne j} \mu_i \mu_j$$

Now proving the statements are equal, I'll operate on both sides of the equality

$$N^{-1} Var(Y) - N^{-k-1} \sum_i (\mu_i - \tau)^2 + \\
+(N^{-k-1} - N^{-2k}) \sum_i \mu_i^2 \\
+(N-1)^{-k+1} N^{-k-1} \sum_R \sum \mu_i \mu_j \\
-N^{-2k} \sum_{i \ne j} \mu_i \mu_j = \\
V(T_R) + \frac{N-1}{N} N^{-k} (N-1)^{-k} \sum_R \sum (\mu_i - \tau)(\mu_j - \tau)$$

Note that $V(T_R) = \frac{1}{N} Var(Y)$

$$- N^{-k-1} \left[ \sum_i \mu^2 - \sum_i \mu_i \tau - \sum_i \mu_i \tau + \sum_i \tau^2 \right] + \\
+N^{-k-1} \sum_i \mu_i^2 - N^{-2k} \sum_i \mu_i^2 \\
+(N-1)^{-k+1} N^{-k-1} \sum_R \sum \mu_i \mu_j \\
-N^{-2k} \sum_{i \ne j} \mu_i \mu_j \\
= \frac{N-1}{N} N^{-k} (N-1)^{-k} \left[ \sum_R \sum \mu_i \mu_j - \sum_R \sum \mu_j \tau - \sum_R \sum \mu_i \tau + \sum_R \sum \tau^2  \right]$$

Cancel terms and re-arrange on the left.  On the right, notice that $\sum_R \sum \mu_i = N^k (N-1)^k \tau$ just like $\sum_i \mu_i = N^k \tau$

Also $\sum_R \sum \alpha = N^k (N-1)^k \alpha$ and $\sum_i \alpha = N^k \alpha$

$$- N^{-2k} \sum_i \mu_i^2 -N^{-2k} \sum_{i \ne j} \mu_i \mu_j \\
- N^{-k-1} \left[ -2 \sum_i \mu_i \tau + \sum_i \tau^2 \right] + \\
+(N-1)^{-k+1} N^{-k-1} \sum_R \sum \mu_i \mu_j \\
= \frac{N-1}{N} N^{-k} (N-1)^{-k} \left[ \sum_R \sum \mu_i \mu_j - N^k (N-1)^k \tau^2 - N^k (N-1)^k \tau^2 + N^k (N-1)^k \tau^2  \right]$$

---

$$- N^{-2k} \sum_i \sum_j \mu_i \mu_j \\
- N^{-k-1} \left[ -2 N^k \tau^2 + N^k \tau^2 \right] + \\
+(N-1)^{-k+1} N^{-k-1} \sum_R \sum \mu_i \mu_j \\
= \frac{N-1}{N} N^{-k} (N-1)^{-k} \sum_R \sum \mu_i \mu_j - \frac{N-1}{N} \tau^2$$

---

$$- N^{-2k} (N^k \tau)(N^k \tau) \\
- N^{-k-1} \left[ - N^k \tau^2 \right] + \\
+(N-1)^{-k+1} N^{-k-1} \sum_R \sum \mu_i \mu_j \\
= N^{-k-1} (N-1)^{-k+1} \sum_R \sum \mu_i \mu_j - \frac{N-1}{N} \tau^2$$

---

$$- \tau^2 + N^{-1} \tau^2 \\
+(N-1)^{-k+1} N^{-k-1} \sum_R \sum \mu_i \mu_j \\
= N^{-k-1} (N-1)^{-k+1} \sum_R \sum \mu_i \mu_j - \frac{N-1}{N} \tau^2$$

---

$$- \frac{N-1}{N} \tau^2 \\
+(N-1)^{-k+1} N^{-k-1} \sum_R \sum \mu_i \mu_j \\
= N^{-k-1} (N-1)^{-k+1} \sum_R \sum \mu_i \mu_j - \frac{N-1}{N} \tau^2$$

Just to check that there really is a typo, I simulated in R and checked with the corrected variance.

```
require(lhs)

N <- 10000
m <- 10
Ylhs_mean <- numeric(N)
Ysrs_mean <- numeric(N)

for (i in 1:N)
{
  Xlhs <- lhs::randomLHS(m, 2)
  
  Xsrs <- matrix(runif(2*m), ncol = 2)
  
  Ylhs <- 3*Xlhs[,1] + Xlhs[,2]
  
  Ysrs <- 3*Xsrs[,1] + Xsrs[,2]
  
  Ylhs_mean[i] <- mean(Ylhs)
  Ysrs_mean[i] <- mean(Ysrs)
}

print(paste("Mean Simple Random Sample: ", mean(Ysrs_mean), " Expected: ", 3*0.5 + 0.5))
print(paste("Variance of mean SRS: ", var(Ysrs_mean), " Expected: ", 1/m*(3^2*1/12 + 1/12)))

print(paste("Mean of Latin hypercube sample: ", mean(Ylhs_mean), " Expected: ", 3*0.5 + 0.5))
print(paste("Variance of mean LHS: ", var(Ylhs_mean)))
```

[1] "Mean Simple Random Sample:  1.99932677709821  Expected:  2"

[1] "Variance of mean SRS:  0.0826009701843071  Expected:  0.0833333333333333"

[1] "Mean of Latin hypercube sample:  1.99986260053744  Expected:  2"

[1] "Variance of mean LHS:  0.000837129404177263"

```
# Y is N vector
# mu is N^k vector
# tau is single number
Vlhs <- function(varY, mu, tau, N, k)
{
  stopifnot(abs(mean(mu) - tau) < 1E-9)
  1/N*varY - 1/N^k/N*sum((mu-tau)^2) +
    (1/N^k/N - 1/N^k/N^k) * sum(mu^2) +
    (N-1)/(N-1)^k/N^k/N*restrictedSum(mu, N) -
    1/N^k/N^k*doubleSum(mu)
}

doubleSum <- function(A)
{
  sum(matrix(A, ncol = 1) %*% matrix(A, nrow = 1) * (1 - diag(1, nrow = length(A))))
}

restrictedSum <- function(A, n)
{
  Am <- matrix(A, ncol = n)
  su <- 0
  for (i in 1:n)
  {
    for (j in 1:n)
    {
      su  <- su + sum(Am[i,j] * Am[-i, -j])
    }
  }
  return(su)
}

expected_x1 <- matrix(1/m/2+(0:(m-1))/m, nrow = m, ncol = m)
expected_x2 <- matrix(1/m/2+(0:(m-1))/m, nrow = m, ncol = m, byrow = TRUE)
expected_y <- 3*expected_x1 + expected_x2

Vlhs(varY = 10/12, 
     mu = c(expected_y),
     tau = 2,
     N = m,
     k = 2)
```

[1] 0.0008333333

Comment: Thank  you very much, it's more clearly  than before

Comment: I'm glad to have helped.  Please upvote and/or accept my answer to indicate it worked for you.

Comment: yes i've accept it (my account are not enough to upvote srr abt that)

Comment: btw i've a few more question around the R code, when you noted #mu is a N^k vector and i've this question related to this is in the (3.2) part of the paper above they said #mu = E(Y(t)) so it's mean i've Y(t) as N vector of Y_1,...,Y_N and mu = 1/N*sum of Y_i and #mu_i = E(Y(t)|X in S_i) for stratified sample which is mean #mu_i = 1/N*sum of N Y_i vector, am i correct? still confuse so much about this when doing simulation on R and with the Latin hypercube are the same????

Comment: Thanks for the acceptance!  Yes, normally, in a lhs, you would have an $NxNxN...xN$ array with the appropriate indexes.  Instead of having $k$ indices, the authors choose to have a vector that is $N^k$ long and index it only by $i$.  It took some thinking for me to get used to it also, but it is equivalent.